# Is a fiber bundle uniquely determined by its holonomy?

Tags: fiber-bundles

Consider two fiber bundles with the same base space (with the same base point). If the holonomy of the two bundles for each loop from the base point to the base point are the same, does this imply the two fiber bundles are equivalent?